# Passing parameter from axios to laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, routes, axios

In my application I'm working with comment, each product has its own comment.Comment in MySql contains column 'computer_comment' with foreign key(id).When I send 'computer_comment' from axios to laravel comments doesn't shown, I guess that 'computer_comment' is null or undefined.

I tried to send 1 or 2 instead 'computer_comment', in this case it works.

CommentComponent.vue

```
<template>
<div>
<div v-for="l in list">
    <div v-if="l.computer_comment==current">
        <div class="card" >
            <div class="card body" >
                <h4 style="text-decoration: underline">{{l.name}}</h4>
                <p >{{l.body}}</p>
            </div>

        </div>
        <br>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</template>
<script>
export default{
    props: ['message'],
    data(){
        return{
            list: [],
            comment:{
                id: '',
                user_comment: '',
                computer_comment: '',
                name: '',
                body: ''
            },
            current: this.message
        }
    },

    created() {
        this.show_comment();
    },
    methods: {
        show_comment(){
            axios.get('/current_comment').then(result => {
                this.list = result.data;
                console.log(result.data);
            });
        },
        removeCom(id){
            axios.post('/remove/'+id).then(result => {
                 this.show_comment();
             }).catch(err => {
                 console.log(err);
             });
        }
    },
}
</script>
```

info.blade.php

```
<div id="info">
    <comment message="{{$computer->id}}"></comment>
    .....
</div>
```

Comment: Where are you getting the `computer_comment` variable from?

Comment: When i get a page 'indexAbout' function with product $id, then assign to $computer_comment=$id, after send this variable to 'indexComment' function as argument.When I'm running `Route::get('/products/info/{id}','CommentController@indexAbout')` page, it simultaneously also runs in vue.js `Route::get('/current_comment/{computer_comment}','CommentController@indexComment')` comments.Only with laravel working, but I need front-end functionality and I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: In your `created` hook you're calling `this.show_comment();` without an argument.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I had done this problem, I used custom component current with props:[''], that holds current computer id and if computer_comment is equal current ,show comments